# Is it possible to cycle through function arguments in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Dagger dependency injection to initiate a list of `Foo` elements that will get passed to another object. Here is essentially the code:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public List<Foo> provideList(@Named("foo1") Foo foo1, @Named("foo2") Foo foo2) {
    List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(foo1);
    list.add(foo2);
    return list;
}
```

As time progresses, we expect to add more and more `Foo` arguments to this method. To make the code more durable, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public List<Foo> provideList(@Named("foo1") Foo foo1, @Named("foo2") Foo foo2) {
    List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();

    args.forEach(arg -> {
        if (arg instanceof Foo) list.add((Foo) arg);
    });

    return list;
}
```

Is anything like this possible in Java?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by Constructor Arguments. Your code does not show any Constructors, do you mean functions/methods instead?

Comment: Not while having a pre-defined number of params.  You could use a method signature like `provideList(Foo... foos)` and then have an array of `Foo` objects you can iterate through.  Also, your first code block can be simplified to `Arrays.asList(foo1, foo2);`

Comment: Why don't you use varargs and can drop the @Named annotation.

Comment: `return List.of(foo1, foo2);`. Unless you change to varargs, that's about as concise as you can get.